# Perform set of numbers as a chromosome for genetic algorithm (1-0 chromosome)

Tags: r, algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I have an algorithm to prepare and would like to record a set of numbers as a chromosome of  zero and ones. I have an idea for fitness function but have no idea of how to prepare a chromosome. For example for set of numbers

```
X = {-2, 1, 4, -3, 3 }
```

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the largest negative number you can have, then you can add that to all of the numbers and then convert to binary. In your example, you have -3 as the largest negative, so I would covert `X` to

```
X={1, 4, 7, 0, 6}
```

Then as binary, you have

```
X={00000001, 00000100, 00000111, 00000000, 00000110}
```

You can convert back at the end of your genetic algorithm.

Comment: why the X is suddently {1, 4, 7, 0, 6}? And I don't want the new set with 5 values but the chromosome - just one - with zero and ones so in that case sth like 0000000100000100000001110000000000000110

Comment: I added 3 to each number. You can concatenate all of those binaries into one, so it would look like this `00000001000001000000000000000110`.

Comment: ahh i see, unfortuately I will never know what will be the largest negative, here its -3 but in other cases it can be -10, -777 etc...

Comment: You could store an extra bit in the front to denote positive/negative. So make them 9 bit strings. For example, -2 would be `100000010`.